# What is the meaning of 流し when talking about swordsmanship?

Tags: meaning, words

What is the meaning of 流し方 in the following sentence?

> 知ってると思うが、剣は腕力より流し方だぜ、力の。

Since it is opposed to 腕力 (brute force), I suppose it has something to do with spiritual force. The context is a fight between two samurai. This is where it's taken from: [i.imgur.com/Yaz1eQr.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIE1S.jpg)
Here's my attempt:

> I think you know, but in swordsmanship, more than brute force, it's the way you make it circulate that's important.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't know, the same character then adds 「力の」, I'll edit the question to add it. Is the correct meaning "more than brute force, i'ts the way you dodge it"?

Comment: It probably refers to sword technique.  I'm basing this on Rurouni Kenshin by the way.  Kenshin's sword school was 飛天御剣流.  The 流{りゅう} was translated to "style" (as in your manner of using a sword) in the English dub .  So 流し方 is probably "way of using technique" which is somewhat redundant in English.

Comment: It's still ambiguous between how you pour your force or how to deflect the opponent's force, but without context I feel the former would be slightly more favorable here.

Comment: No I don't think ～流【りゅう】 ("school/faction") is relevant. I believe 剣は力の流し方だ in such a sentence is "Swords are all about how you deflect the energy (of the opponent's attack)". "Parrying is as important as (or more important than) brute strength" is something even I know, and that is true for modern fencing and *kendo*.

Comment: If you're still unsure please tell us a few sentence that follow. Are they talking about attacking or defending?

Comment: I think you are right. His enemies are accusing the samurai of not fighting seriously. He then answer the sentence written above, and then adds 「 お前ら相手には期待されてるような本気は出せない」, which should be something like "I'm not fighting seriously only according to your expectations", right? This is from where it's taken: http://i.imgur.com/Yaz1eQr.jpg

Comment: @Marco Ah, so here "剣は腕力より力の流し方" is treated as a famous sayings. He implies "As you know, real swordsmen like me don't take other people's attacks straight. And in the same vein, (you should know) real swordsmen don't accept meaningless challenges."

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! If you write it like an answer I'll mark it as correct. Can you confirm I got the meaning of the sentence that follows right?

Comment: @Marco I'd rather prefer this to be resolved as duplicate. Thanks :)　「 お前ら相手には期待されてるような本気は出せない」 literally is "Against you, I can't exert my full power that is expected (by you)."

Comment: Thanks again! Ok, how do I do it? I mean marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: on a grammatical point to 流す something is to "let is flow past" what ever it might be, if you 流す it, it does not register or effect you. eg. if someone is saying harsh words you just 聞き流す or "let it go" . here 流し方 would be the referencing the way to do so.